# PHP - Check if hash has expired

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to check if a hash I've stored in my database is expired, i.e older than 30 minutes.

This is my check

```
$db_timestamp = strtotime($hash->created_at);
$cur_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
if (($cur_timestamp - $db_timestamp) > ???) {
    // hash has expired
}
```

Comment: As unix timestamps are in seconds, then the value for comparison is 30 * 60 = 1800

Comment: And you don't need `$cur_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`, just use `$cur_timestamp = time()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamps are numbers of seconds, so you want to see if the age of the hash (in seconds) is greater than the number of seconds in 30 minutes.

Figure out how many seconds there are in 30 minutes:

```
$thirtymins = 60 * 30;
```

then use that string:

```
if (($cur_timestamp - $db_timestamp) > $thirtymins) {
    // hash has expired
}
```

---

You can also cleanup the code by doing the following:

```
$db_timestamp = strtotime($hash->created_at);
if ((time() - $db_timestamp) > (30 * 60)) {
    // hash has expired
}
```